# Trying to show a ListView in a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to show a ListView, with my custom adapter in a Fragment, but it doesn't appear. I use the same code that I used in a normal activity and it worked but in this fragment no...

the code gives no error, but nothing appears.

[image]

```
public class Amics extends Fragment {
    ListView listView_Amics;
    ArrayAdapter<Usuari> adapter;
    List<Usuari> list = new ArrayList<Usuari>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.amics, container, false);


        listView_Amics = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_amics);
            adapter = new MyAdapter_Amics(getActivity(),list);
            listView_Amics.setAdapter(adapter);

    obtenir_amics1();  // THIS FUNCTION ADD ELEMENTS TO THE LIST AND SETS ADAPTER

        return rootView;
    }

    public boolean obtenir_amics1(){
    String data = null; // THE STRING TO SAVE HTTPOST RESPONSE

        // HTTP POST DATA RECIEVING..
        List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("MY_HOST");
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametres));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Log.e("DADES OBTINGUDES", data);

            try {

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(data);
                int limit = 50;
                if(json.length()<limit){limit=json.length();}
                for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String nombre = obj.getString("usuario_two");
                    boolean selected = false;
                    Log.e("amic:", nombre);

                list.add(new Usuari(nombre,selected));


                listView_Amics.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                return true;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIENT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: After adding new items in your adapter, try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` method.

Comment: the same problem keeps happening.. But thank you!

Comment: Did you check your script php outside your app, is it working? Does it return something? Maybe it's not related but you should create an AsyncTask and display your items inside onPostExecute method. Perhaps android doesn't like to do a HTTP request in the main thread..

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onResume()` method and shift  `adapter = new MyAdapter_Amics(getActivity(),list);
listView_Amics.setAdapter(adapter);
obtenir_amics1();`to `onResume()`.

Comment: Like this?   @Override
 public void onResume(){
  adapter = new MyAdapter_Amics(getActivity(),list);
  listView_Amics.setAdapter(adapter);
         
  obtenir_amics1();

 }

Comment: It don't works.. I have to write super.OnResume(); ??